# owncloud mount folders disappear

Tags: amazon-ec2, bitnami, owncloud

I recently installed Owncloud 4.5 (beta) and on 4.0.7 (latest stable) on Bitnami LAMP stack as amazon ec2.

after installation I've been trying to use the external storage app to mount a backet from S3, FTP, or dropbox. in all of the cases soon as I set up the configurations in the app, the mount folder disappear from the client's browser. when I ssh and look the folders are still there. 
only thing that works is the option to mount local folders.

I did try to change permissions and ownership of those folders but that not seems to be the case.

posted on forum.owncloud.org as well, but no one seems to answer.

Did anyone seen this problem before?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try if you can reproduce this with the latest ownCloud? 7.0.2?